# How can I use replaceWith() in two locations with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a "Add to wish list" button the will need to update onClick in two locations.

1. In the mouse over popup, and
2. in the onClick modal (using simpleModal 1.4.1).

The code below works in both locations, when I click on "Add to List" on the mouse over popup.

However, when I click on the same link in the modal, it does not reflect in mouse over popup.

```
$("a.addedToList").live("click", function (e) {
    addToShoppingList($(this).parents('.product').attr("OfferID"));
    $(this).text('Add to Shopping List');
    $(this).replaceWith(function () {
        return $("<span class='itemAdded'>" + $(this).html() + "></span> ");
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Will I need to update each in individually?  I am using a "multi-tabbed" layout, and every product is treated the same.  This will make targeting a specific product difficult.

Comment: Someone might as well say it, as so 1.7 `on` should be used instead of `live`

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You first say it works in both places, then you say it doesn't. Which is it? what doesn't work?

Comment: The site has a lot running, upgrading will cause 'problems'.  It works on the mouse over popup but not in the modal.

Comment: The question is still unclear. You specify `$(this).replaceWith()` so this will only work against the one element clicked in the DOM. If you want to update/replace 2 elements they must share a common attribute value e.g. a class name or a data- attribute.